# Create a robust permission control

Tags: users

I am building a system in Drupal and here is one question that is blowing my mind for more than a month and I hope you guys can help me.

My user access control inside the system must work like this:

1) I have a role called partners and I have lots of permissions assigned to this role partners.

2) I have a role called clients and again, I have a bunch of permissions assigned to this role.

3) The users with a partner role can create users with role partner AND client. The users with role client can create users with role client.

So far it is simple!

4) A user with role partner can create users with role partner and client BUT they can also say that the new partner or client created MUST NOT access some specific areas. So for example: A partner is allowed to see users, create users and create clients. When the ¨partner master¨ is creating a new partner user, he can say that this new user can only see users and create users but not create partners.

Do you know any module to solve this problem? I have already tried user_permission and subrole, none of them fit :(

Hope you can help, thanks!

BTW, I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the role delegation module? Sounds to me like your already using it but I may be wrong. It allows users with certain roles to act like the administrator. You can limit which roles can be granted.